# IDE(s) or text editor for web + mobile app dev team?

Tags: php, android, ios, flash, webos

We are putting together a web dev team that will also be building complimentary iOS, Android and webOS mobile apps, and are trying to standardize our toolset between team members. We are working on OS X, but can run Windows or Linux virtual machines if necessary. On the web the majority of our work is currently in Drupal (PHP), but are looking at moving to Ruby on Rails in the next few years. Also, we use git for version control if it matters.

Our primary experience is in web development, so the tools we're most familiar with are glorified text editors like BBEdit, Coda, CSSEdit, etc. For Flash work we've just used what's built into Adobe Flash Pro.

Apple provides their own Xcode IDE for iOS, which is also the only native mobile app development we've done so far. webOS (Enyo) is so simple, we could continue doing that in a text editor. Google seems to be pushing Eclipse for Android work, but claim to be compatible with other environments.

**Should we try to find one editor to rule them all, or just go with each of the separate environments above?** Eclipse seems to be popular but not very intuitive. NetBeans seems to be popular mostly because it's free. IntelliJ seems to have a small but passionate following.

Web and web app development will remain our primary focus, so I'm reluctant to invest in a steep learning curve for a mobile IDE if it won't also benefit our web work.

Any input from similar cross-discipline experience is welcome.

Comment: for Flash check out the FDT plugin for eclipse: http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/ 

(or Flash Builder but i would recommend FDT - great coding experience and worth the money)

Comment: @pkyeck Have you used Flash Builder as well? I.e., what do you prefer about FDT over Adobe's Flex tools?

Comment: yep, i'm using both. but most of the time FDT. flash builder (also eclipse based) only for mxml/AIR app development. but FDT added mxml support (as well as haxe) a while ago - so you can also do the mxml stuff there. additionally FDT has **live-error-highlighting** which is a **great** plus. all in all FDT works much smoother than flash builder ... there's also a great community behind FDT so you get lots of support through blogs/tutorials/etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode is most likely to be able to handle everything best.  I say this because you will find it difficult to impossible to effectively develop for iOS without using Xcode, even if you use tools like PhoneGap because at some point you'll almost certainly have to use Xcode anyway to get provisioning right.  Essentially any tool can be made to work for webOS, and as for Android I think you'll find it possible to work in Xcode but it won't be as easy as if you worked in Eclipse.

In short, I'd say use the right tool for the right job, and don't worry about using multiple tools.  In the end you'll probably be happier supporting multiple development environments than struggling to cram your work into a single tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why Eclipse would not be intuitive for your needs. I've been doing web development and Android development in Eclipse for quite a while now. It helps to have an eclipse book, or a quick guide and it does take some time to get used to but you'd be hard pressed to a better platform, especially one that Google pushes for Android Development.

I should note that I have not programmed on Eclipse for iOS so another input might be needed in that regard.

But Eclipse is free. And it has a lot of documentation and users so you'll find a wealth of support if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I obviously need to do more research as I didn't realize Eclipse was free. How have you used it for web development? What do you prefer about it over a text editor?

Comment: I've mostly been using Eclipse to develop portlets. I've found that it's very easy to organize your project and organizes your files in an intuitive manner. It is easier to debug if there's a problem as you can view the webpage in eclipse, not to mention catch errors as you are programming. You can also configure eclipse to work with a server so you don't have to go back and forth uploading the webpage if you are hosting it.

Answer (score 0):

I just attended a user group about developing for the major devices yesterday... The overriding opinion seems to be you should develop in the vendors preferred IDE (XCode for iOS, Eclipse for Android, Blend for WP7, TextPad or NotePad++ for WebOS).

Question for you though... Are you planning on developing WebOS for Mojo or Enyo? That *may* change your strategy slightly... My understanding is that Eclipse has a plugin to make Mojo development easier. I've been doing Enyo development in Notepad++ however, and it's been pretty simple.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: I'm only planning on working with Enyo at this point. webOS will be available on the Pre 2 and up, so while I won't be able to run my apps on the original Pre sitting in my desk, that's just the cost of being an early adopter.

Comment: I may be eating my words. I just read [This Is My Next interview](http://thisismynext.com/2011/07/14/dewitt-rubinstein-interview-exclusive/) and it sounds like HP is changing their [story from March](http://www.precentral.net/webos-3-enyo-details-tidbits). I may end up learning Mojo for webOS 2 after all!

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against using anything other than XCode for iOS development.

If you are familiar with Eclipse already, I would also strongly advise moving from Flash Professional to Flash Builder (which is based on Eclipse) as Flash Pro is not an IDE per se. Doing so will at least position you such that Android development and Flash development can be done in similar/the same IDE's.

Generally speaking, it's best to use IDE's that are designed for the task at hand.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on moving to Flash Builder. I had that confused with Catalyst... would not mind getting out of Flash Pro at all!

Comment: Yes, Adobe have not done a good job managing the "Flash" brand name. They've used it for pretty much anything from the runtime engine, to the browser plugin to a variety of completely different development tools.

Comment: Once you realize that you can extend MovieClip for your base application class, and import assets directly from pngs (or even from swf libraries), there is very little reason to use "Flash Professional" from a technical standpoint, as moving your project to being entirely code-based and loading assets for what they are (graphical assets), it becomes easier to manage by an order of magnitude.